# Java SSL socket layered over existing socket SSLSocketFactory: does it require a host parameter?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, networking

The class [`javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) defines a method [`createSocket​(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#createSocket(java.net.Socket,java.lang.String,int,boolean)), which returns an instance of [`SSLSocket`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html).

I'm trying to understand this method, so my question is: why does the method take a host parameter? Shouldn't the host be read from the plain socket's underlying `getInetAddress().getHostName()`, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Following the implementation in SSLSocketFactoryImpl, it would return new SSLSocketImpl, as in here you can see the following snippet of code

```
        if (peerHost == null || peerHost.isEmpty()) {
            boolean useNameService =
                    trustNameService && conContext.sslConfig.isClientMode;
            useImplicitHost(useNameService);
        } else {
            conContext.sslConfig.serverNames =
                    Utilities.addToSNIServerNameList(
                            conContext.sslConfig.serverNames, peerHost);
        }
```

(Note that peerHost is same as the host parameter)

So i think the point here is that if you don't provide the hostname, it would take a little more effort to lookup to do some stuff to get the hostname - You can follow  `useImplicitHost(useNameService)` to see the logic in there in case the host is missing